# API resolved without sending a response - Next.js

Tags: api, next.js

I've this code to get nearby places and nearby beaches from a point, with Google maps. This is called from a Next.js component, via the `useSWR` hook.

All the data is returned correctly, but before first Axios call (`const fetchNearbyPlaces = async (urlWithToken = null) => {...`), I'm receiving this error in the console:

> API resolved without sending a response for /api/google/places/33.807501/-78.70039, this may result in stalled requests.

I can't figure out what the error is, although there may be several because I'm a novice. I appreciate any suggestion.

```
const axios = require("axios");
const GetNearbyPlaces = async (req, res) => {
  const {
    latitude,
    longitude,
  } = req.query;

  const radius = 50000;

  const types = [
    "airport",
    "tourist_attraction",
    "amusement_park",
    "aquarium",
    "art_gallery",
    "bar",
    "museum",
    "night_club",
    "cafe",
    "restaurant",
    "shopping_mall",
    "store",
    "spa",
  ];

  function checkFunc(arr, val) {
    return arr.some(arrVal => val === arrVal);
  }

  const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${latitude}%2C${longitude}&radius=${radius}&key=${process.env.CW_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}`;

  const beachesUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${latitude}%2C${longitude}&radius=${radius}&type=natural_feature&key=${process.env.CW_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}`;

  try {
    let results = [];
    let beaches = [];
    const fetchNearbyBeaches = async (urlWithToken = null) => {
      await axios.get(urlWithToken ? urlWithToken : beachesUrl).then(data => {
        beaches = [...beaches, ...data.data.results];
        if (data?.data?.next_page_token) {
          const newUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=${process.env.CW_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}&pagetoken=${data.data.next_page_token}`;

          setTimeout(() => {
            fetchNearbyBeaches(newUrl);
          }, 2000);
        } else {
          beaches.length > 5 && beaches.splice(5);
          results.length > 5 && results.splice(5);

          const finalResults = [...beaches, ...results];

          finalResults.length > 10 && finalResults.splice(10);
          return res.status(200).json({
            data: {
              results: finalResults,
            },
            success: true,
          });
        }
      });
    };

    const fetchNearbyPlaces = async (urlWithToken = null) => {
      await axios.get(urlWithToken ? urlWithToken : url).then(data => {
        results = [...results, ...data.data.results];
        if (data?.data?.next_page_token) {
          const newUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=${process.env.CW_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}&pagetoken=${data.data.next_page_token}`;

          setTimeout(() => {
            fetchNearbyPlaces(newUrl);
          }, 2000);
        } else {
          const dirtyResultsWithDuplicates = [];
          results.map(result => {
            return types.map(type => {
              if (checkFunc(result.types, type) && !result.types.includes("lodging")) {
                dirtyResultsWithDuplicates.push(result);
              }
            });
          });

          const set = new Set(dirtyResultsWithDuplicates);
          const filtered = Array.from(set);

          results = filtered.length > 10 ? filtered.splice(10) : filtered;
          
          return fetchNearbyBeaches();
        }
      });
    };

    fetchNearbyPlaces();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
      message: err.message,
      statusCode: 500,
    });
  }
};

export default GetNearbyPlaces;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the backend application not the frontend component.

Nextjs expects a response to have been sent when the api handler function exits. If for example you have a `databaseCall.then(sendResponse)` in your api handler function what happens is that the handler function exits before the database returns.

Now this is not a problem if the database does return after that and sends the response, but it is if for example the database has an error. Because the handler function exits without a response already being sent Nextjs can't be sure that at that point there isn't a stalled request.

One way to fix this is by await-ing the db call(or whatever other async function you call) thereby preventing the handler function from exiting before some kind of response has been send.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was added this object to mi API code.

```
export const config = {
  api: {
    externalResolver: true,
  },
};
```

Documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/request-helpers

Comment: This only hides the warning so you shouldn't use this unless you actually use an external resolver to handle requests for this route.

Comment: ok, I'll unmark it as a valid answer then. But initially I only used the function to get places (not beaches) and the code worked correctly, the problem started when I added a function to get beaches. So I don't think there is really a problem in the backend, but in the way the data is retrieved. I mean, I don't understand why there shouldn't be a way to fix the error from the front-end.

Comment: Nextjs here *is* the backend, just your backend also calls another api. 


You can add await to every async function call and that would probably also do the trick.

We've (at my job) mostly stopped using `.then` in favour of `x = await ...` that would also linearize the flow of data.

The problem the warning points out is that the handler returns before a response has been sent. The contents of `axios.then` executes after the handler has exited.

Comment: ok, I haven't tried overriding ``.then``. I'm going to try that. Thank you very much